# How to properly select an object in an angular dropdown menu in a ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic 1 app and I need some help to simplify my code and understand the best way to get around this thing:

I have a json like this:

```
[{"Cod":"A","Denumire":"production","Culoare":"#808000","ID":"1","Activ":"1"},
{"Cod":"B","Denumire":"transportation","Culoare":"#C4FFC4","ID":"2","Activ":"1"}]
```

and it's assigned in my controllers.js to ***$scope.categories***

What I want is to load it in a drop-down menu and set the selected value to a variable ***snag.CategorieID*** which I have in the html page.

***I want to assign it from the html and not the controller!***

The problem is that ***snag.CategorieID*** is the ID from ***$scope.categories*** and it seems to me first I have to find out the index of the object ***$scope.categories*** that has the ID == ***snag.CategorieID***.

I have managed to get it working like this:

```
<label class="item-borderless item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Category
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="c in categories">
      <div ng-if="c.ID == snag.CategorieID">
          <select ng-init="snaginf.category = categories[categories.indexOf(c)]" ng-model="snaginf.category" ng-options="cat.Denumire for cat in categories"></select>
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

The thing is even if it works I have the feeling things should be simpler.
Could anyone help me simplify it?

Thanks in advance,
Rares

Comment: Why do you have the selector inside an ng-repeater, I mean it is for any particular reason?

Comment: I have it there to go thru the categories and find out the index of the category that has the ID=snag.CategorieID(the id I will have dynamic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a fun of ng-init since the code should be in the controller, but if you must do it that way, you can use a filter to get the category using a categoryID like this:

```
  <select ng-init="snaginf.category = (categories | filter: {ID: snag.CategorieID})[0]" ng-model="snaginf.category" ng-options="cat as cat.Denumire for cat in categories track by cat.ID"></select>
```

In this piece of code snaginf.category saves all the category object and assumes the ID of the categories is unique.

The filter takes the categories array and returns a new array with those categories which their ID equals snag.CategorieID. Since it's supposed to return only one category inside the array, we just get that element using [0].

Comment: Sweet! This works like a charm. This is what I was after! Cheers!

Comment: Also now I have a new problem and that is what happens if `snag.CategorieID` is `null` or 0. In this case I would like the dropdown **to be populated but no value selected**. This code selects the first value in these cases. A trick I used is `<div ng-if="snag.CategorieID != 0">` and then load your dropdown and in case it's 0, I load a plane one like so `<select ng-model="snaginf.category" ng-options="cat.Denumire for cat in categories"></select>`. Could this be done in a single line so I can avoid the if?

Comment: I tried it and if the snag.CategorieID is null or 0 the ng-model stays empty and the dropdown is empty. But if you want to be sure you can add an empty option inside the select (if you want you can put an ng-if in the option). Like this:

<option value="">Select one</option>.

Check this CodePen: https://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/NdGOaq?#

Comment: thanks for the reply again. Your code does indeed work well. For some reason in my app even with the `<option value="">Select one</option>` it still doesn't work. I think I have to dig some more. Maybe also update my Ionic lib. Thanks for your replies they have helped me out a great deal!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep just the selector in place.

```
<select ng-init="snaginf.category = categories[0]" ng-model="snaginf.category" ng-options="cat.Denumire for cat in categories"></select>
```

Live Sample:
http://play.ionic.io/app/c0a0efd8603b

Comment: The problem is I need to set it dynamic! And this gives me the first index. I actually need to set it by the ID in categories(in this case the index and the ID match, but they will come from a database and the index and ID will not match at some point). So instead of categories[0] I would like tho have categories[the index where ID=ID I want]

Comment: Got you! and why you want to assign it from the html and not the controller?

Comment: The state I use is like this: `url: '/snag/:snagID'` and from there I go thru a list of all the snags and load the data from the one where ID==snagID like so:             `<div ng-repeat="snag in snags">
              <div ng-if="snag.ID == snagID">` and inside all that I use the dropdown menus.